# byte order of 16 bit field in C

Tags: c, endianness

Assume I have a 16 bit or 4 hex characters field and data in it is in little endian

This is little endian

```
 B8 00 00 00
```

I want big endian of above

Should it be

```
 00 00 00 B8
```

or

what?

or If I have char  1 byte "0x1D" should it be same?

or if I have array[2]={0xiD,2E} what would be big endian data should it be of the following.

Comment: For chars (1-byte entities), there is no difference of course. For larger types, you simply reverse the order of the bytes.

Comment: That's not 16 bits, its 32 bits. Or did you intend that to represent two 16bit values. Each of those `XX` values is 8-bits.

Answer (score 1):

> Should it be `00 00 00 B8`

If this is the binary representation of a 32 bit integer, then yes.

> If I have char 1 byte "0x1D" should it be same?

Endianess only applies to words (2, 4, 8 bytes data types), not to bytes. That is, integer or floating point types.

> if I have array[2]={0xiD,2E} what would be big endian data

That doesn't make sense unless this is the binary representation of a larger type. Endianess doesn't apply to raw data (or strings).

More info here: [What is CPU endianness?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640)

Comment: so if I am reading string so it doest mater whether I reverse it or not. So if I have string thats produced by extracting the binary data
from a data collection unit running an Intel CPU? then should I revers it or not if I am not different endianess

Comment: @user786 If you reverse a string, it will be reversed... so it matters. But that has nothing to do with endianess - big & little endian machines store strings identically (lowest address=first letter).

Answer (score 0):

Little Endian representation of value `0x000000B8` at address `N`:

- Value at address `N+0` is `0xB8`
- Value at address `N+1` is `0x00`
- Value at address `N+2` is `0x00`
- Value at address `N+3` is `0x00`

Big Endian representation of value `0x000000B8` at address `N`:

- Value at address `N+0` is `0x00`
- Value at address `N+1` is `0x00`
- Value at address `N+2` is `0x00`
- Value at address `N+3` is `0xB8`